# VBA code to list all months between a range of dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA in Excel.  I have looked through through the forum, but have not found an answer for my specific date VBA I am looking for.  I have three date ranges in excel cells per row of data elements representing testing dates.  Each of the three ranges has a start date and an end date columns A-F.

For each row of test date ranges, I would one cell in column G to calculate the month and year "MMMYY" for any months covered in any of the three date ranges.  If the date ranges over three months, the resulting cell would list all three months.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Marc

```
                                                          Calculated VBA column G
   A         B       C         D        E         F       G
1  T1 Start  T1 End  T2 Start  T2 End   T3 Start  T3 End  Months
2  02Nov20   16Nov20 17Nov20   19Nov20  02Nov20   1Jan21  Nov20
                                                          Dec20
                                                          Jan21
3  28Oct19  15Nov19  28Oct19   01Nov19  28Oct19   1Nov19  Oct20
                                                          Nov20
4  20Jul20  21Aug20                                       Jul20
                                                          Aug20
5  11Sep20   29Sep20  20Sep20  22Sep20  20Sep20           Sep20
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Why does row3 list Oct**20** etc.?

Comment: If you need to use VBA, use a dictionary or collection object to create a unique list, then use that object to create your output string.  Post back with your code attempt. If you still need help, add the code to your question and post a comment here; if it works, post it as an answer.

Comment: @Storax Exactly.  I would have thought that if a test starts in November, and ends in January, that December (the month in-between) should be included, as shown in his first row of testing.  I guess his example of the desired result is not what he really wanted.  He wrote *If the date ranges over three months, the resulting cell would list all three months.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a macro that outputs ALL of the included month/year.

In order to find the data table, I used the `.CurrentRegion` property of the cell that contains `T1 Start`.  Because of this, if the output were adjacent to the table, the second run would include that column.  Accordingly, I wrote the results one column over (and hid the intervening column.  But you could make any number of changes in determining the source table size if that is undesireable.

I also was not certain, from your screenshot, if the Dates were "real Excel Dates" formatted to look like `ddmmmyy` (except for Column F in your text table) or if they are strings.  So there is code to account for the different things I see.  Code could be simplified if the data is in a known format.

The output is text strings and the column is formatted as text. If you want the output to be real dates formatted as `mmmyy`, then code will need to be added so Excel does not erroneously convert 2 digit years to day of the month.

Be sure to read the notes in the macro, as it will help you understand what's going on.

```
Option Explicit
Sub mthList()
    Dim cM As Collection
    Dim rg As Range, dStart As Date, dEnd As Date
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim i As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim d1 As Double, d2 As Double 'start and end dates

    Dim WS As Worksheet, rRes As Range

'Find the table and read it into VBA array
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WS
    Set rg = .Cells.Find(what:="T1 Start", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Data Table"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    vSrc = rg.CurrentRegion
    ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 1)
End With

'Collect all the included dates
'Convert date strings to real dates if they are strings
For i = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
Set cM = New Collection
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2) Step 2 'can have N pairs of dates
        If vSrc(i, J) <> "" Then
            d1 = theDate(vSrc(i, J)) ' need to make sure this is a date and not a text string
                If vSrc(i, J + 1) = "" Then
                    d2 = d1
                Else
                    d2 = theDate(vSrc(i, J + 1))
                End If
            On Error Resume Next 'remove duplicates since Collection cannot have two entries with same key
            For K = d1 To d2
                    cM.Add Format(K, "mmmyy"), Format(K, "mmmyy")
            Next K
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next J

    'Output the data to results array
    For K = 1 To cM.Count
        vRes(i, 1) = vRes(i, 1) & vbLf & cM(K)
    Next K
    vRes(i, 1) = Mid(vRes(i, 1), 2)
Next i

'write the results
'formatting is optional, and Styles may not work with non-English versions
Set rRes = rg.Offset(0, rg.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 1)
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = vRes
    .WrapText = True
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Style = "output"
    .Offset(0, -1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End With

With rg.CurrentRegion
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Style = "Input"
End With

End Sub

Private Function theDate(d) As Double
    If Not IsDate(d) Then
        theDate = CDate(Left(d, Len(d) - 5) & " " & Mid(d, Len(d) - 4, 3) & " " & Right(d, 2))
    Else
        theDate = d
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

To use my algorithm as a function, just need to remove all that stuff with regard to finding the table and writing results back to the worksheet:

```
Option Explicit
Function mthList(rg As Range) As String
    Dim cM As Collection
    Dim dStart As Date, dEnd As Date
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim d1 As Double, d2 As Double 'start and end dates
    Dim S As String

'Collect all the included dates
'Convert date strings to real dates if they are strings
vSrc = rg
Set cM = New Collection
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2) Step 2 'can have N pairs of dates
        If vSrc(1, J) <> "" Then
            d1 = theDate(vSrc(1, J)) ' need to make sure this is a date and not a text string
                If vSrc(1, J + 1) = "" Then
                    d2 = d1
                Else
                    d2 = theDate(vSrc(1, J + 1))
                End If
            On Error Resume Next 'remove duplicates since Collection cannot have two entries with same key
            For K = d1 To d2
                    cM.Add Format(K, "mmmyy"), Format(K, "mmmyy")
            Next K
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next J

    'Output the data to a string

    For K = 1 To cM.Count
        S = S & vbLf & cM(K)
    Next K
    mthList = Mid(S, 2)
End Function

Private Function theDate(d) As Double
    If Not IsDate(d) Then
        theDate = CDate(Left(d, Len(d) - 5) & " " & Mid(d, Len(d) - 4, 3) & " " & Right(d, 2))
    Else
        theDate = d
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay; both of you are very helpful.  Busy working on multiple projects and selling a house.  @Ron Rosenfeld;  You are correct I need it to encompass all the dates in a range.  I applied Storax code and looked at a few of the data points and thought I was good, posted, and then moved on to working on the house.  I used the function listMthYear in a formula selecting the range in the formula for each line of data.  On closer inspection if the range spans three months the middle month is not included.

Comment: .@Ron Rosenfeld   The data I used as an example was just pasted into another sheet and posted.  The actual data is burred a large table with various other data points, text, dates and numbers.  I applied you code and made the corrections for sheet name and I get a runtime error 5 (data in cells before the date ranges) and runtime error 13 (data in cells after date ranges).  I entered blank columns before and after the data range, but I believe the issues is with the table header columns.  Removing the table would cause problems in the workbook.

Comment: Is there an easy way to modify Storax's code to include the middle month or make Ron's code usable as a function whereby selecting range example:  Cell A4 currently has Storax's function based on the VBA =listMthYear(O4:T4)?  I like the ability to use the code as a function.  Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: @MarcBrackett See my Edit for use as a function.  The code is a bit simpler

Comment: Thank you.  The code works great, I ran a few tests just to make sure it worked in many ranges and over calendar year crossing.  I appreciate the notes so I can lean and understand the logic and syntax.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments one could use a dictionary

```
Function listMthYear(rg As Range) As String
' Goto Tools/Reference and check Microsoft Scripting Runtime 
Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = New Dictionary

Dim sngCell As Range

For Each sngCell In rg
    If IsDate(sngCell.Value) Then
        Dim mth As Long
        Dim yr As Long
        Dim dte As Date
        dte = sngCell.Value
        mth = VBA.Month(dte)
        yr = VBA.year(dte)
        dte = VBA.DateSerial(yr, mth, 1)
        ' This will create an unique entry in the dictionary if not already created
        dict(dte) = dte
    End If
Next sngCell

Dim output As Variant, i As Long
output = dict.Keys
For i = LBound(output) To UBound(output)
    output(i) = Format(output(i), "MMMYY")
Next i

listMthYear = Join(output, vbLf)

End Function
```

You could use the function as an [UDF](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html) or like that

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A3:E3")
    MsgBox listMthYear(rg)
End Sub
```

Comment: Storax, Thank you for your assistance and your prompt response.  The code worked flawlessly once I incorporated the module function into the multiple worksheets and referenced the function in the formulas.

Comment: @MarcBrackett This function seems to return only the first and last months of the range. I thought you wanted all of the months in the range.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: It returns all the months from the dates contained in the cells. But if there is no date for a certain month it will not return this month. That's how I understood the OP.

Comment: Based on his example of what I thought were his desired results, I thought he wanted **all** of the months **inclusive** from start to end.  But since he accepted your answer, I guess that's not what he really wanted.  See his first row of testing. He wrote *If the date ranges over three months, the resulting cell would list all three months.*

Comment: Good point. I haven't paid that much attention to that before. As said, my function will only list the months which actually appear in the list.